# Odd experiment results (electromagnetics)

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, experimental-physics, magnetic-fields, acceleration

Okay, a bit of background. So I'm working on a linear accelerator (you might know it as a Gauss rifle), and I had worked through the equations I thought I needed (Magnetic force, displacement, etc.)

When I tested, it didn't work. I wondered if there was a short in my electromagnet coils, so I used a compass to see if there was a magnetic field. I found that there was a magnetic field, so I got my multimeter and checked the amperage through the coil. That too, was right where it should be. I was using CVCC device to limit the current, so I took that off and shorted the power source straight across the coils. Nothing. Now I'm just not sure what's wrong. Does anyone have any ideas?

I'm using the below to move a piece of plate metal and a nail 4.5 cm:

- 300 wraps of 22 AWG gauge magnet wire
- 5 Amps of current
- The surface area of the plate I am trying to move is about $5\text{cm}^2$
- The distance between the plate and the coils is about 4.5cm
- The mass of the plate, and what it is attached to is about 20g
- The electromagnet pulls the plate against a spring with 350g compression*

*the problem is not that the electromagnet cannot pull against the spring, it is that the electromagnet does not move the plate at all.

The equations I was using were $$F = (NI)^2\mu_0A/2g^2$$ for the force exerted on the plate in Newtons, where N is the number of turns, I is the current, A is the area of the plate, and g is the gap separating plate and coils.

I then rearranged $F=ma$ to $\frac{F}{m}=a$ and used $F = (NI)^2\mu_0A/2g^2$ for force. I also used the mass of the plate plus the compression weight of the spring, for mass.

With the above equations and the list of values, the electromagnet should exert 0.349N. With my mass + spring, it should accelerate the plate at almost 1m/s (0.943m/s). Given that it only has to travel 4.5cm, it should do that really quickly.

Honestly, I don't know what went wrong. I don't suppose anyone can point out if I missed something glaringly obvious?

*pictures of electromagnet:

[Electromagnet](https://5bbbafd3-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/picturehostingsites/home/storage/IMG_4199.JPG?attachauth=ANoY7cqLRAWIy7MQIuzExCTA7r7XE4C8AFSbRyY2ldNgxAVKZAd2r7kBHePQEPabFnLa95ttoeNAs0__WoCW8IotCbjJi5nkh0CDYeSLygqFLW5JFedQc-EB9N0IzVDPSzx67hFku4QyoJkDzU1veCnzIg28_eWsgJq-EPR0vET8rYLJqUK61NkIRlHsZ-68fjFPeSmJAg3Myd5lXpI3mU35K5sNHiHScJUS-frYCcenhQpb7qE46Tw%3D&attredirects=0)

[Plate (extended)](https://5bbbafd3-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/picturehostingsites/home/storage/IMG_4200.JPG?attachauth=ANoY7cogcAbGBmJ5AND0rzYrRLDulg5-SDdkoAyY4LPjpLixm1k42XIhFBby76KD3R99im7O2ywB56bHsOjtBC-CkrYLpbh_aJDaNenoswTJlXjXG89TghQGhScKZfSABB1pysYl4Q4oGyVp7AL4w1RzpPBX1zFV1uK9WBJ9XUW86gkRQpNkOJvpWH0CcU0mluxqvpdSGHpGIHetaIcs6ieBbtHHVOYuV2laBusWx3xDcpUQxU6LWjo%3D&attredirects=0)

[Plate (compressed)](https://5bbbafd3-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/picturehostingsites/home/storage/IMG_4201.JPG?attachauth=ANoY7coywltb8vWx0tE6s7VnUfy-6puMPD-EwONqCqMfKRtHD_F4y_-LtuSOrryXAVYLfTgy66KTmD9IqyntpoHjJkvz0P6OZxVOScXJEyixSuxOoo4sSHjnoSNs5tJhvotoyM7J5WbhmClYq-lSdHLMLNXaY0vc6IYIZos47CrVZHbJ56s2gQsfNKLkrE3DsgFOnHjUpxORQS4BUhrIYZlKRg1K_5vWolyCePnk9-ksSsC1gZP7Wwo%3D&attredirects=0)

Comment: Give it time, dude.

Comment: @DanielSank Yes, I know. Actually, I meant "Does anyone see anything glaringly obvious, like I'm using the wrong equations?"

Comment: What material is the plate made of? metal is not enough, its magnetic properties are important.  Easy to check with a small permanent magnet.

Comment: Your very first problem is that the magnetic path is wide open. Your magnetic field lines are going all over the place, but not where you need them: trough the plate.  This is not how one would build an efficient electromagnet. An efficient design will include a yoke that returns the magnetic field lines on the shortest path possible. Take a look at how the professionals are building magnets that can produce serious force: http://www.wagner-magnete.de/en/content500.html.

Comment: @annav Sheet metal. I checked before I glued it in, it _is_ ferromagnetic.

Comment: @CuriousOne You mean a ferromagnetic core? There is a nail that I am using as a guide rail. It is almost fully inside the coil when it is fully extended. Also, I think of this as a solenoid.

Comment: @CoilKid: You don't just need a core but also a return path around the back of the coil. If you have your plate riding on your core nail, it's shorting out the field, anyway, since it's passing trough the nail behind the plate, rather than trough the plate. Seriously, look at the professional lift magnets, they work. You can probably build them out of different size washers by stacking.

Comment: @CuriousOne So I may be able to solve this by removing the guide nail? That might solve some other problems also. I could replace with wood...

Comment: @CuriousOne Honestly, if that turns out to be it, I'll be very relieved. (My whole design relies on a small piece of metal being pulled into a coil.) **Edit:** Also, with the washers, do you mean put washers _behind_ the coil, or _in front_ of it? Behind is doable, but I'd have to rebuild if I need them in front.

Comment: Here is the basic design of a magnet for lifting: http://www.rfcafe.com/references/Electricity-Basic-Navy-Training-Courses/images/electricity-navy-basics-103.jpg. Try to build something like that with washers and see if you like the result.

Comment: @CuriousOne rebuilt without any metal except the plate. Still doesn't work. Could my coil being irregularly wound affect it?

Comment: @CuriousOne I plan to add iron washers to the end of my coils, as I've heard they can improve efficiency greatly. Is that true?

Comment: You take a little hit from having an irregular coil, but that's mainly fill factor and current density. Winding nicely by hand is not a big deal, anyway, just takes a bit more time. Your main problem remains the magnetic return path. Do yourself a favor and surround your coil, at the very least, with a bunch of nails in addition to the washers.

Comment: @CuriousOne Ah, a ferromagnetic material _around_ the coils as well. Wouldn't that limit the field to around the nails? Path of least resistance and whatnot?

Comment: Take a look at what the professionals are doing. Imitate. A couple of years down the road you will understand the theory behind it. No need to get frustrated until then.

Comment: @CuriousOne Solved my issue. I believe that my force equation is not applicable for pulling at a distance (a holding magnet). Testing revealed it to only be accurate when the object to be acted on was nearing the coil, and aimed to enter them.

Comment: I don't know under what circumstances that formula holds, it certainly isn't useful for what you have in mind. A simple solenoid without a magnetic return path doesn't even come close to being efficient for moving objects.